Create user in Active Directory in ASP.NET using C#
Basically I am trying to create a user in my .NET application with C# and the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.
My problem is that I get an authentication error while setting an attribute of a new user I try to create. And I'm 1000% sure that it's the right credentials as well as the right permissions.
My file with the logic for the new user in AD:
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace guest_register.Services
{
    public class ActiveDirectoryServices
    {
        private readonly string _domainName;
        private readonly string _ldapPath;
        private readonly string _adminUser;
        private readonly string _adminPassword;

        public ActiveDirectoryServices(string ldapPath, string domainName,string adminUser, string adminPassword)
        {
            _domainName = domainName;
            _ldapPath = ldapPath;
            _adminUser = adminUser;
            _adminPassword = adminPassword;
        }

        public void createGuest(string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Connecting to LDAP path: {_ldapPath} with user: {_adminUser}");

                using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domainName, _ldapPath, _adminUser, _adminPassword))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Connected to LDAP successfully.");

                    using (UserPrincipal userPrin = new UserPrincipal(context))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Created a UserPrincipal");
                        // Set properties for the user
                        userPrin.SamAccountName = userName;
                        userPrin.SetPassword(password);
                        userPrin.Enabled = true;

                        // You can set other properties as needed
                        userPrin.Save();
                        Debug.WriteLine("Successfully created user");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (PrincipalOperationException pex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Message pex: {pex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is how I start this service:
using guest_register.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new ActiveDirectoryServices("DC=radius,DC=internal", "192.168.45.130", "demo", "test-123"));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

And a snippet of the file which calls the functions to create the user:
try
{
    _adService.createGuest("test-123", "test-123");
    return Ok("User created successfully");
}

Does someone have any idea of what is going wrong?
I tried to mess around with the credentials as well as the permissions. I also had the ContextOptions set in the PrincipalContext but this also didn't help.
I couldn't find any resources as how it failed as most tutorials just didn't use credentials at all...
Edit:
Connecting to LDAP path: DC=radius,DC=internal with user: demo
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\coding\guest-register\guest-register\bin\Debug\net6.0\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Connected to LDAP successfully.
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\coding\guest-register\guest-register\bin\Debug\net6.0\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
Debugging:
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'guest-register.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in guest-register.dll


Can you add the full exception message and stacktrace to your question

Can you run the code locally?

@stuartd I am running the code locally on my pc

Oh ok sorry, it’s just that there isn’t much information in the exception message.

Yeah it just tells me that the user password or username is incorrect

@stuartd i could not bother anymore i just joined the pc the domain and it works now
